# How to change the corner radius of UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol

Is it possible to change the corner radius of UISegmentedControl? I have tried the following approach which we use to change a UIView's corner radius.

```
self.segmentedControl.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0;
self.segmentedControl.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

This did not work as you can see it only cuts off the UISegmentedControl's corner:

[image: cut off corner]

Answer (score 109, accepted):

This should work:

```
self.segmentedControl.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0;
self.segmentedControl.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
self.segmentedControl.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
self.segmentedControl.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

You need to specify the border after setting cornerRadius.

Comment: It works only if you want to increase the cornerRadius

Comment: It doesn't fix the initial problem with only corners being cut off. See my answer below.

Comment: For Swift: 
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0;
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor;
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true;

Comment: @Manish How do you add the UISegmentedControl? I've tried in iOS 13 and it works well.

Comment: @user2185354 Could you upload a demo?

Comment: @Manish check my answer for editing the corner radius from iOS 13 and above by setting the CALayer its maskedCorners property https://stackoverflow.com/a/60651341/5324541

Answer (score 39):

## iOS 13 / 14 - FINALLY WORKING!!!

[image: image alt]

I decided to give it another go, and I finally got it working perfectly!!
There's one line of code that fixed it all! Check out the code

**Code**:

```
class CustomSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl{
    private let segmentInset: CGFloat = 5       //your inset amount
    private let segmentImage: UIImage? = UIImage(color: UIColor.red)    //your color

    override func layoutSubviews(){
        super.layoutSubviews()

        //background
        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height/2
        //foreground
        let foregroundIndex = numberOfSegments
        if subviews.indices.contains(foregroundIndex), let foregroundImageView = subviews[foregroundIndex] as? UIImageView
        {
            foregroundImageView.bounds = foregroundImageView.bounds.insetBy(dx: segmentInset, dy: segmentInset)
            foregroundImageView.image = segmentImage    //substitute with our own colored image
            foregroundImageView.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: "SelectionBounds")    //this removes the weird scaling animation!
            foregroundImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            foregroundImageView.layer.cornerRadius = foregroundImageView.bounds.height/2
        }
    }
}

extension UIImage{
    
    //creates a UIImage given a UIColor
    public convenience init?(color: UIColor, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)) {
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    
        guard let cgImage = image?.cgImage else { return nil }
        self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
}
```

The idea is that Apple uses a UIImageView with its own square image and tint for the selected moving segment. What we want to do is instead overwrite its image so we have control on the color, corner radius, etc. After that, we want to remove one of Apple's 3 default animations (the one that was problematic made the segment scale up on touch -- I used `foregroundImageView.layer.animationKeys()` to find out what animations were affecting the moving segment)

Comment: The round rect is working. But how did you change the background color of selected index. In my case is set for both active and inactive case.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it's the `foregroundImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray` line

Comment: Hi @RaimondoPrevidi Do you got any solution for that changing frame?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I just used what apple gave us, sacrificing the rounded corners. For me, it was not worth investing more hours to try and break apple's code.

Comment: Take a look at this solution.


https://kenb.us/how-to-customize-uisegmentedcontrol-without-losing-your-mind


 class SegmentedControlAnimationRemover {
    static var shared = SegmentedControlAnimationRemover()
    @objc func removeAnimation(_ control: UISegmentedControl) {
        control.layer.sublayers?.forEach { $0.removeAllAnimations() }
    }
}

segmentedControl.addTarget(SegmentedControlAnimationRemover.shared, action: #selector(SegmentedControlAnimationRemover.removeAnimation(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

Comment: I tried removing animations but it wasn’t changing anything. I’ll have to try this, maybe calling it on valueChanged might work.

Comment: @GR1995 So, right now I could only test this on a simulator, and it seems to work MUCH better, however I'm pretty sure I'm still noticing a small "growing" animation. I will test it on a device as soon as I can. I got frame drops from the simulator.

Comment: @GR1995 Ok so I tried it on my device and it doesn't change much. The weird animation between switching segments is definitely gone (there's still a bit of grow-shrink animation, but I think that's on me, probably due to changing its bounds in `layoutSubviews()`). Regardless, it still does its full awkward animation when tapping the currently selected segment (grows-shrinks a lot, in place). I tried with .allEvents but no changes. Also, for some reason, adding this code completely removed the sliding animation on my first segmented control, and only the first time I change its value. lol weird

Comment: No, I let this one go for the time being. I'm soon upgrading the project to iOS 14, so I'll try this again and see if it's now doable

Comment: @Merricat I managed to achieve some radius stuff (ofcourse without animation)  see my Gist: https://gist.github.com/anoop4real/deffa9bbed3741b6c3f19c07d8c87502 ... following this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58315497/selectedtintcolor-of-segment-control-is-not-rounded-corner-on-ios-13 + some tweaks

Comment: Currently not at home and can't try this... I got the round corners to work in my code above, but the problem was the weird animations when interacting with the segmented control! Does your code still have this animation issue?

Comment: @Merricat, excellent solution.  Did you tried to remove background light grey color

Comment: @AnilKumar Thanks! No, I didn't need to remove the grey background, so I never tried :)

Comment: This answer works well for me. Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Image extension not needed --> set backgroundColor of foregroundImageView to some color and image to nil

Answer (score 36):

Embed UISegmentedControl inside UIView and set corner radius for **UIView**.

*Objective-C*

```
outerView.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetHeight(outerView.bounds) / 2;
outerView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
outerView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
```

*Swift*

```
outerView.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetHeight(outerView.bounds) / 2
outerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
outerView.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

[image: Cornered UISegmentedControl]

Comment: and don't forget to add Clip subviews to UIView in storyboard

Comment: @Ilario please explain

Comment: It's a setting in the Interface Builder. If you don't enable it on the parent view, the child (UISegmentedControl) can extend beyond the parents borders.

Answer (score 14):

The segmented control is not going to change the way it draws its corners, so it is continuing to draw its corners in its own way and you are then cutting them off. You are not in charge of how a segmented control draws its boundary shape. If you truly don't like the way it's drawn, you'll have to devise your own substitute control from scratch. The closest you can legitimately come to the kind of thing you're trying to do is to set the segmented control's background image.

Comment: I will pass it to designers:)

Answer (score 11):

You're able to change the **UISegmentedControl** cornerRadius by increasing the layer its **cornerRadius** or from **iOS 13 and above** by setting the layer its **maskedCorner** property.

This example removes the default **cornerRadius** and straightens the **backgroundImage**:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    segmentedControl.layer.maskedCorners = .init()
} else {
    segmentedControl.layer.cornerRadius = 0
}
```

Source:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/2877488-maskedcorners

Comment: Thanks, but that does not affect the corner radius of the "moving" segment, only the background ones :( Edit: I finally found a way to access the "moving" view in the hierarchy with `let  movingSegment = subviews[numberOfSegments] as? UIimageView` (basically it's the segments' backgrounds, then the moving one, then the foregrounds (i.e. each segment's title), so the "moving" view is always in the middle). Then I set the Image and highlightedImage to and empty UIImage(), inset the imageView's bounds by 5, and set the backgroundColor to the desired color.

Comment: It looks exactly as it should, the problem is that during the tap animation the view grows as large as the segmentedControl, then shrinks again, so it looks wrong. Note that I'm doing these changes in the segmentedControl's `layoutSubviews()`. Look at my answer below to see my current results.

Comment: @RaimondoPrevidi If u set a custom background image for the selected state is it still changing it's corner radius when moving?

Comment: The problem is that I want the title, not an image. And on the docs it says you can only have one or the other.

Answer (score 6):

Updated for Swift 3 & Xcode 8.2 compatibility

```
mySegmentedControl.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
mySegmentedControl.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
mySegmentedControl.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
mySegmentedControl.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 6):

There are some changes in iOS13. Hence you must set the borderRadius from within `layoutSubviews`:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    layer.cornerRadius = 2
}
```

Comment: hey, do you have any idea how to change the corner radius of the selectedSegment view?

Comment: I don't know. I wouldn't recommend it either. With the right amount of engineering time you can create any layout, but is it worth the time? I would lean the UX desinger towards UX that Apple has built-in itself and avoid micro customazation

Comment: This is gold, thank you for sharing. Note: you can move to layoutSubviews other setters too, to get them properly applied. I needed borderWidth myself.

Comment: @RaimondoPrevidi check my answer for editing the corner radius from iOS 13 and above by setting the CALayer its maskedCorners property https://stackoverflow.com/a/60651341/5324541

Comment: Easy! Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The previous solutions never worked for me. My solution is:

To embed the `UISegmentedControl` inside a superview, then assign -1 to the constraints leading, trailing, bottom, top, in order to cut off the `UISegmentedControl` border. 
Finally the superview should be configured in this way:

```
segmentedControl.superview.clipsToBounds = true
segmentedControl.superview.layer.cornerRadius = 0 //whatever
segmentedControl.superview.layer.borderWidth = 1
segmentedControl.superview.layer.borderColor = segmentedControl.tintColor.CGColor
```

Answer (score 3):

Your result is because something other (custom drawing?) controls the border and not the layer. Luckily it seems that that layer settings have priority.

If you know what border color you need, you can just add (example):

```
self.segmentedControl.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
self.segmentedControl.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
```

Comment: how does it change corner radius?

Comment: This doesn't change the corner radius. It just supplements the original code posted in the question to get the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

This is a converted and working code for **Swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.3** of [Yakiv's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33422620/5969121).

```
segmentedOuterView.layer.cornerRadius = segmentedOuterView.bounds.height / 2
segmentedOuterView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
segmentedOuterView.layer.borderWidth = 1
segmentedOuterView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 3):

---

### Rounded corners of the view and its selectedSegment

---

1. **Create a custom subclass of UISegmentedControl:**

   ```
   final class SegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {
       private var cornerRadius: CGFloat

       init(cornerRadius: CGFloat) {
           self.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
           super.init(frame: .zero)
       }

       required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
           fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
       }

       override func layoutSubviews() {
           super.layoutSubviews()
           layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius

           guard selectedSegmentIndex >= 0,
               let selectedSegment = subviews[numberOfSegments] as? UIImageView else {
               return
           }

           selectedSegment.image = nil
           selectedSegment.backgroundColor = selectedSegmentTintColor
           selectedSegment.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: "SelectionBounds")
           selectedSegment.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius - layer.borderWidth
           selectedSegment.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(
               width: selectedSegment.bounds.width,
               height: bounds.height - layer.borderWidth * 2
           ))
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Create an instance of SegmentedControl and don't forget to set `selectedSegmentTintColor` and also make sure you didn't change `isMomentary` to true**

[Screenshot with **segmentedControl.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGray5.cgColor** and **segmentedControl.layer.borderWidth = 5**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZZ0L.png)

Comment: this is the best solution I've found working on iOS 17. Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain how the following line works: 
```guard let selectedSegment = subviews[numberOfSegments] as? UIImageView else {
            return
        }
```

If you have 3 segments, `numberOfSegments` is always 3... How does it properly set the initial selected segment? Is the `subviews[3]` always the selected segment in the subviews array?

Comment: @Weston Mitchell Thanks for your question (after that I found a bug and fixed it). Now my solution will work if you don't change `isMomentary` property to true. So, If you look at the debug view hierarchy in Xcode when you changed the selected segment - that segment went to the end of the UISegmentedControl subviews array. It would be incorrect to say "always", but according to my experience this solution worked in all cases. Therefore if we have 3 segments and for example your `selectedSegmentIndex == 1`, `subviews[3]` will always be the selected segment.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code :

```
segmentContrl.layer.borderColor=*anycolor*.CGColor;
segmentContrl.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0;
segmentContrl.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
```

Comment: This will usually work . Provide your code so that i can look into it !

Comment: Check with some value for corner radius-
segmentContrl.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;