# How to set rounded corner for the Segment Control in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin, xamarin.forms

After adding Segment Control from code behind in Xamarin.Forms PCL using below code, How can I set rounded corner for the segment control?

```
SegmentControl segment = new SegmentControl();            
segment.AddSegment("Segment 1");
segment.AddSegment("Segment 2");            
segment.AddSegment("Segment 3");
segment.AddSegment("Segment 4");            
segment.SelectedSegment = 0;
segment.Padding = new Thickness(5,5);
segment.TintColor = Color.FromHex("#0282C3");
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**SegmentControl** is specific to **iOS**.  **Xamarin.Forms** doesn't have there own implementation.

To change the styling of the **SegmentControl** you can use the **ControlStyle** property as shown [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/segmented_button_control/configure_segments_(uisegmentedcontrol)/).

With regard to the **CornerRadius** you can adjust it by setting `layer.borderWidth`, however there are issues with this getting truncated in the rendering as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317645/how-to-change-the-corner-radius-of-uisegmentedcontrol).

So apart from rendering your own custom control, it appears the answer is no - you can't , but it all depends on what value your wanting to use for the corner radius.

It may be best to write your own custom renderer perhaps, unless you are not targeting **Android** or **WindowsPhone** and only **iOS**, otherwise how will you represent this on those platforms?