# UISegmentedControl Corner Radius Not Changing

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, uisegmentedcontrol

**UISegmentedControl** corner radius is not changing. I also followed some answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317645/how-to-change-the-corner-radius-of-uisegmentedcontrol) question, my UISegmentedControl's corner radius still is not changing. I followed [This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWBqdOjZ2S4&t=14s) to create UISegmentedControl.

Code:

```swift
import UIKit

class SegmentViewController: UIViewController {

    private let items = ["Black", "Red", "Green"]
    lazy var segmentedConrol: UISegmentedControl = {
        let control = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
        
        return control
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setupViews()
    }
    fileprivate func setupViews(){
        view.addSubview(segmentedConrol)
        
        segmentedConrol.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false //set this for Auto Layout to work!
        segmentedConrol.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        segmentedConrol.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
        segmentedConrol.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
        segmentedConrol.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        segmentedConrol.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
        //style
        segmentedConrol.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        segmentedConrol.layer.borderWidth = 2
        segmentedConrol.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        segmentedConrol.backgroundColor = .red
        segmentedConrol.selectedSegmentTintColor = .darkGray
//        segmentedConrol.clipsToBounds = true
        segmentedConrol.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

}
```

(PS. Probably the answer is so simple for most people, please do not mind me, I am new in this field.)

Comment: Good news, bad news. You aren't doing something that is simple - it doesn't look(to me) as though `cornerRadius` does anything for a `UISegmentedControl`. (BTW, your code looks good to me.) Back in the day (I'm semi-retired) I'd respond to a question like this with: "Could you show me a working example of what you want?" Short of creating your own segmented control, you may be stuck here.

Comment: Hi, I will try my best to demonstrate what I want more clearly. Peace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass `UISegmentedControl` and override `layoutSubviews`. Inside the method set the corner radius to what you want it to be, and you can remove the portion where you set the corner radius in `setupViews()`:

```
class YourSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layer.cornerRadius = 20
    }
}
```

In your view controller where you create `segmentedControl` create an instance of `YourSegmentedControl` like below.

```
lazy var segmentedConrol: YourSegmentedControl = {
            let control = YourSegmentedControl(items: items)

            return control
        }()
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. Do you know why it only works by overriding the function. I am really curious that why in the tutorial I was following it was working fine but not in my code/Xcode?

Comment: I believe that UISegmentedControl received a large update in iOS 13, and the control now draws its rectangle with a default corner radius of 15. From what I've read, you don't have access to change the corners after it is created. If you were to drop down to iOS 12 for your build target and run it on a device running iOS 12 I believe what you had would work.